# How to use Windows API AuditEnumerateCategories function in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell, advapi32

I want get the current [Advanced Security Audit Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn319056(v=ws.11).aspx) using PowerShell. I could use `auditpol.exe`, but its ouput is different per OS language, which makes it difficult to parse.

The [settings](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/03/11/getting-the-effective-audit-policy-in-windows-7-and-2008-r2/) are stored in a REG_NONE value in `HKEY_Local_Machine\Security\Policy\PolAdtEv`. I could try to parse the value with the help of [that unofficial structure table](http://www.kazamiya.net/en/PolAdtEv). My preferred approach, however, is to use the Windows API function `AuditQuerySystemPolicy` of `advapi32.dll`.

With the great help of [this](http://david-homer.blogspot.de/2016/08/document-windows-advanced-audit-policy.html) article, I created a Type in PowerShell as follows.

```
$MemberDefinition = @'
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool AuditEnumerateCategories(
        out IntPtr ppAuditCategoriesArray, 
        out uint pCountReturned);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool AuditLookupCategoryName(
        ref Guid pAuditCategoryGuid, 
        out StringBuilder ppszCategoryName);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AuditEnumerateSubCategories(
        ref Guid pAuditCategoryGuid, 
        bool bRetrieveAllSubCategories, 
        out IntPtr ppAuditSubCategoriesArray, 
        out uint pCountReturned);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool AuditLookupSubCategoryName(
        ref Guid pAuditSubCategoryGuid, 
        out StringBuilder ppszSubCategoryName);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern void AuditFree(
        IntPtr buffer);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool AuditQuerySystemPolicy(
        Guid pSubCategoryGuids, 
        uint PolicyCount, 
        out IntPtr ppAuditPolicy);
'@

$Advapi32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MemberDefinition -Name 'Advapi32' -Namespace 'Win32' -UsingNamespace System.Text -PassThru
```

The Type is created successfuly, but I fail with the first step - to get the GUIDs of all audit categories. I have issues with the different types. I tried for example

```
$guid = [Guid].MakeByRefType()
$count = [IntPtr]::Zero
[Win32.Advapi32]::AuditEnumerateCategories([ref]$guid, [ref]$count)
# Exception calling "AuditEnumerateCategories" with 2 Arguments: "The value "System.Guid&" of the type "System.RuntimeType" cannot be coverted to "System.IntPtr".
```

I also tried to change the `AuditEnumerateCategories` definition output from `IntPtr` to `Guid`. The output of `ppAuditCategoriesArray` is

> A pointer to a single buffer that contains both an array of pointers to GUID structures and the structures themselves.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to handle that in PowerShell.

Comment: If `$guid = [System.Int64]0; $count = [System.Int64]0` then `AuditEnumerateCategories` method returns `IntPtr` and `Int32` values, respectively (as declared in `$MemberDefinition`).

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Well, with the help of @JosefZ I now have the correct count number in `$count` and some number in `$guid`. However, I did not yet manage to get the GUIDs from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take up a [`Marshal.PtrToStructure` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (`.NET`). For instance, [`PtrToStructure(IntPtr, Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx) marshals data from an unmanaged block of memory to a newly allocated managed object of the specified type, see the following *commented* code snippet:

```
### (unchanged)
### $MemberDefinition =  …
### $Advapi32 = Add-Type … 

$guid  = [System.Int64]::MinValue            ### or ### [System.Int64]0
$count = [System.Int32]::MaxValue            ### or ### [System.Int64]0

$aux = [Win32.Advapi32]::AuditEnumerateCategories([ref]$guid, [ref]$count)

$guidArr = @()                               ### array to store GUIDs

$guidPtr = [int64]$guid                      ### pointer to next GUID
$guidOff = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([type][guid])
$ppszCategoryName = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

for ( $i=0; $i -lt $count; $i++ ) {
    $guidAux = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::
                      PtrToStructure( [System.IntPtr]$guidPtr,[type][guid] )
    $guidArr += $guidAux           ### update array of GUIDs for future use
    $guidPtr += $guidOff           ### shift pointer to next GUID

    ### debugging: try another method of [Win32.Advapi32] Runtime Type 
    $foo = [Win32.Advapi32]::AuditLookupCategoryName([ref]$guidAux,[ref]$ppszCategoryName)
    ### debugging: show partial results
    Write-Host $('{0} {1,4} {2,4}' -f $guidAux.Guid, 
                      $ppszCategoryName.Capacity, $ppszCategoryName.Length)
}
```